# How to calculate age using query builder in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have saved the date of birth in  MySQL database.

```
table name : **users**
field name : **dob**
```

now I want to show age on view. My query is :

```
$user_info = DB::table('users')->select('(year(curdate())-year(dob)) as age')->get();
```

I'm using Laravel 5.5.

but this is creating error. How to calculate age using query builder in laravel?

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to make a custom attribute in your `app/User.php` model.

For example:

In your `User.php`

```
public function getAgeAttribute() {
    return $this->dob->diffInYears(\Carbon\Carbon::now());
}
```

In the `controller` and/or `view` you can now access this method as a attribute, by doing the follow:

```
Auth::user()->age;
```

This will set a attribute in your User model based on the `getAgeAttribute()`.

For more information, take a look at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Answer (score 5):

You can use `selectRaw` and then use mysql function like this

```
$user_info = DB::table('users')
                ->selectRaw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DATE(dob), current_date) AS age")
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define a function in your model like this

```
public function age() {
    return $this->dob->diffInYears(\Carbon::now());
}
```

after that you can call it like this

```
{{ $user->age() }}}
```