# Laravel where age clause

Tags: laravel

I have a Student model and it has properties such as full_name, birthdate, ...
birthdate is a date type column.

how can I filter my students and find those students with more than 20 years old?

something like:

```
$students = Student::whereAge('birthdate', '>=', 20)->get();
```

Comment: Are you storing `age` as a number? Or just the birthdate? Also, the 2nd answer here shows how to calculate "age" from a timestamp column: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51654439/3965631

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `whereAge` as `Age` should be a column that exists in your database in that case.

You can try this instead:

```
$students = Student::whereYear('birthdate', '>=', now()->subYears(20)->year)->get();
```

Even better maybe to compare the exact date 20 years ago:

```
$students = Student::whereDate('birthdate', '>=', now()->subYears(20))->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using raw SQL:

```php
$students = Student::whereRaw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, CURDATE()) >= 20');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove -20 years from today's date, and then compare it to the birthdate. Like so:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' -20 year'));

$students = Student::whereDate('birthdate', '<', $date)->get();
```